# How to know the broker that is the active controller?

Tags: apache-kafka

Other than using JMX is there any other way to know, whether a broker is an ActiveController?

I know that the cluster generates a metric `kafka.controller:type=KafkaController,name=ActiveControllerCount`, but I cannot find which broker is the active controller.

Is it necessary to write a JMX client to know it or is there another (better?) way?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can find the active controller using the `zookeeper-shell` tool as follows:

```
./bin/zookeeper-shell.sh [ZK_IP] get /controller
```

Comment: Really Cool.. Thanks a lot!, and For someone who would like to find this out via prometheus monitoring, I would suggest [this as a starting point](https://www.robustperception.io/monitoring-kafka-with-prometheus/)

Comment: If you're using `bitnami` then do `/opt/bitnami/zookeeper/bin/zkCli.sh`. Once connected `get /controller`. To list all brokers do `ls /brokers/ids`.

Answer (score 10):

Perhaps easier way, since you don't need to have kafka and it's zookeeper-shell.sh, is using command line to connect to zookeeper's client port with:

```
nc [zookeeper_ip] [zookeeper_port]
```

or

```
telnet [zookeeper_ip] [zookeeper_port]
```

and then executing

```
dump
```

It will print sessions with ephemeral nodes and one can see which broker is a controller by finding session that contains /controller path

For example, a dump result like this:

```
Sessions with Ephemerals (3):
0x266542cfaa90000:
    /brokers/ids/1
0x166542cfe670001:
    /brokers/ids/3
0x166542cfe670000:
    /controller
    /brokers/ids/2
```

means that controller is a broker whose broker_id is 2.

Comment: This is a nice one.

Comment: This should be the right and generic answer because it is not necessary that the node path will be `/controller` for everyone.  one can also execute `echo dump| 127.0.0.1 2181` from the zookeeper host itself.

Answer (score 1):

Also by calling zookeeper-shell.sh twice, we can get directly the broker name that is the active controller, instead of the broker id.

Example for a zookeeper instance running on localhost:

```
/opt/kafka/bin/zookeeper-shell.sh localhost get /brokers/ids/$(/opt/kafka/bin/zookeeper-shell.sh localhost get /controller|tail -1|jq .brokerid)|tail -1|jq .endpoints[]
```