# Auto deletion VIA zookeeper CLI

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

we want to delete a topics permanently as follows

stop the brokers

remove the directories on disk

```
rm -rf <kafka_data_dir>/<topic_name>*
```

remove the topic from zookeeper:

we can print all topics by the follwing command

```
kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper $Zookeeper_IP:2181 --describe
```

and get the zoo cli as:

```
bin/zkCli.sh
```

now we delete the topics

```
rmr /config/topics/<topic_name>
rmr /brokers/topics/<topic_name>
rmr /admin/delete_topics/<topic_name>
```

example for `/brokers/topics/`

```
rmr /brokers/topics/topic3435
rmr /brokers/topics/topic3443
rmr /brokers/topics/topic3436
rmr /brokers/topics/topic3433
rmr /brokers/topics/topic3432.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
```

verify the topic directory is deleted in zookeeper:

```
ls <path>
```

start the brokers back up

re-create the kafka topic if needed

**until now I described the manual steps**

our goal is to delete the topics by rmr with script or expect script
instead of manual rmr steps

I will happy to get suggestions

Comment: Any reason why you don't use kafka-topics.sh or the AdminClient API to delete topics? These are the proper way to delete topics.

Comment: from my experience when we use the API - kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper @zookeper_IP:2181 --alter --topic Topic_Name --config retention.ms=1000  , then we get mark for deletion and after time topic still appears , so we not have choice ,and this is the reason that we use the approach that I explained in my question

Comment: please see also the  - https://github.com/darrenfu/bigdata/issues/6

Comment: we also use ./kafka-topics.sh — zookeeper localhost:2181 — delete — topic <topic_name>   , and also get mark for deletion ,

Comment: @ Mickael Maison regarding to what I said in my comments , do you have suggestions ?

Comment: can you give please you opinion in answer ,

Comment: are you running with topic auto creation enabled on the brokers?

Comment: this parameter is false , we can see it from our ambari dashboard

Comment: so I still not understand what is wrong with my procedure , please advice

Comment: @Mickael Maison  can you please answer as post regarding to my question with explain what is your opinion about my procedure?

Answer (score 2):

I really recommend using the AdminClient API or the `kafka-topics.sh` tool to delete topics instead of manaully editing zookeeper.

When you use `kafka-topics.sh` with the `--zookeeper` flag, the deletion is asynchronous. The tool will return as soon as the deletion as been requested. In practice the topic can still exist for a little while.

If you use the AdminClient API or `kafka-topics.sh` with the `--bootstrap-server` flag, it will block until the topic is deleted or the timeout reached. With recent Kafka releases, deletion usually happens within a few seconds, so if you specify a timeout, you can make it synchronous.

Comment: I have a question please - you right better to use  - kafka-topics.sh , bet lets say we have 100 topics and 20 of them are deleted successful and the other not , then can we use Judy procedure to remove the other topics ?

Comment: second question please , we have very old kafka cluster version - 0.1 , do you think the command that you mention still relevant for kafka version - 0.1 ? , and dose we need to delete with command CLI on each kafka in the cluster , or maybe we can use the cli on one of the kafka in the cluster in order to delete all topics ?

Comment: In case some topics are not deleted, I'd first force a controller re-election (by either deleting the /controller node in zookeeper, or restarting the controller). The new controller should continue the deletion. Only if that's not successful I'd consider deleting the topics as described in the question.

I'm guessing you are using 0.10 as 0.1 never existed. This release is over 3 years old. You should really upgrade to a newer release. Topic deletion improved a lot since then.

Comment: about what you said - , I'd first force a controller re-election , can you give example for that?  second how to restart the controller ?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48287339/how-to-know-the-broker-that-is-the-active-controller/48287856#48287856 to find which broker is the current controller. Then either restart that broker or delete the `/controller` node is zookeeper using `delete /controller`.

Comment: Dear Mickael , just to be more clear , and do the procedure that you mentioned , can I get your approval to post question with all steps ( include kafka topic deletion command , and what need to do if deletion not successfully )  , and get you feedback again , because I fell discussion by comments is less clear then real post that described step by step the procedure