# Find the lead of kafka cluster using kafkacat

Tags: apache-kafka, kcat

I have kafka cluster in docker containers created using this [tutorial](https://better-coding.com/building-apache-kafka-cluster-using-docker-compose-and-virtualbox/).
When I run `kafkacat -L -b kafka-1:19092` i get:

```
Metadata for all topics (from broker 1: kafka-1:19092/1):
 3 brokers:
  broker 2 at kafka-2:29092
  broker 3 at kafka-3:39092
  broker 1 at kafka-1:19092
 1 topics:
  topic "__confluent.support.metrics" with 1 partitions:
    partition 0, leader 2, replicas: 2,3, isrs: 2,3
```

How can I find the lead broker? I would like to kill it and see behavior of cluster after electing new lead.

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48287339/how-to-know-the-broker-that-is-the-active-controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clusters have a single ***controller***.

***Topics*** have leaders

```
topic "__confluent.support.metrics" with 1 partitions:
    partition 0, leader 2, replicas: 2,3, isrs: 2,3
```

Comment: Also, that tutorial doesn't understand Kafka networking because editing /etc/hosts is the wrong advice

Comment: what is the better solution?

Comment: And how to find which node is the controller-node?

Comment: RE: controller - see comments above. "better solution" for the hosts file is to understand the `advertised.listeners` variable in the `server.properties` file (or `KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS` in the Docker variables)