# how to find consumer group coordinator in kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka

Is there any command that gives me the id of the broker that is acting as coordinator for my consumer group in kafka?

Similarly, I need id of controller broker.

We can find it from log files but I want it to know without going through logs

Comment: Why do you need such information?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can find a consumer group coordinator with `kafka-consumer-groups` commands. E.g.:

```
kafka-consumer-groups --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --group sample --describe --state

GROUP                     COORDINATOR (ID)          ASSIGNMENT-STRATEGY  STATE           #MEMBERS
sample                 localhost:9092 (0)        range                Stable          1
```

For more information, please, see [Managing Consumer Groups](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#basic_ops_consumer_group)

> Similarly, I need id of controller broker.

Please, check [How to know the broker that is the active controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48287339/how-to-know-the-broker-that-is-the-active-controller)